# Error ao realizar teste com Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, textarea, body

Bom dia pessoal, alguem q ja teve experiência com Laravel Dusk que possa me ajudar?
Não consigo fazer a Authenticação pelo Browser para poder ter acesso as telas, no meu caso eu tenho diferentes guards, mas segundo a documentação o q estou fazendo deveria dar certo.. Segue codigo do Teste abaixo:

public function testLogin()
   {
       $manager = factory(Manager::class)->create();

```
   $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($manager) {
       $browser->visit($this->getUrl().'manager/login')
           ->type('email', $manager->email)
           ->type('password', '123123')
           ->press('Entrar')
           ->assertPathIs('/manager/home')
           ->assertSee('Inicio');
   });
```

}

O error é o seguinte:

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ManagerTest::testLogin
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='email']"}
 (Session info: headless chrome=66.0.3359.181)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar o erro.

No meu arquivo .env precisava colocar APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000 , pois percebi que ele insere a url na frente. então o código ficou assim.

```
   $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($manager) {
        $browser->visit('/manager/login')
            ->type('email', $manager->email)
            ->type('password', '123123')
            ->press('Entrar')
            ->assertPathIs('/manager/home')
            ->assertSee('Inicio');
   });
```

Visitei algumas referencias que forma de grande importância:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-dusk-example-auth-test-not-workin?page=1

https://scotch.io/tutorials/introduction-to-laravel-dusk

Vlw.